# pyspark: From an array of structs, extract a scalar from the struct for even or odd index , then postprocess the array

Tags: arrays, pyspark

I have a dataframe row that contains an `ArrayType` column named `moves.`  `moves` is an array of `StructType` with a few fields in it.  I can use a dotpath to fetch just one field from that struct and make a new array of just that field e.g. `.select(df.moves.other)` will create a same-length array as `moves` but only with the values of the `other` field.  This is the result:

```
[null, [{null, null, [0:10:00]}], null, null, [{null, null, [0:10:00]}], [{null, null, [0:09:57]}], [{null, null, [0:09:56]}], [{null, null, [0:09:54]}], ...
```

So clearly `other` is not simple.  Each element in the array is either `null` (idx 0,2,and 3 above) if 'other' is not in the struct (which is permitted) or an array of struct where the struct contains field `clk` which *itself* is an array (note that simple SPARK output does not list the field names, just the values.  The `null`s in the struct are unset fields).  This is a two-player alternating move sequence; we need to do two things:

1. Extract the even idx elements and the odd idx elements.
2. From each, "simplify" the array where entries are either `null` or the value of the zeroeth entry in the `clk` field.
   This is the target:

```
even list:  [null, null, "0:10:00", "0:09:56", ...

odd list:   ["0:10:00", null, "0:09:57", ...
```

Lastly, we wish to walk these arrays (individually) and compute delta time `(n+1 - n)` iff both `n+1` and `n` not null.

This is fairly straightforward in "regular" python using slicing e.g. `[::2]` for evens and `[1::2]` for odds and `map` and list comprehensions etc. etc.   But I cannot seem to assemble the right functions in pyspark to create the simplified arrays (forget about converting `0:10:00` to something for the moment).  For example, unlike regular python, pyspark `slice` does not accept a step argument and pyspark needs more conditional logic around `null`s.  `transform` is promising but I cannot get it to skip entries to arrive at a shorter list.

I tried going the other direction with a UDF.  To start, my UDF returned the array that was passed to it:

```
    moves_udf = F.udf(lambda z: z, ArrayType(StructType()))

    df.select( moves_udf(df.moves.other) )
```

But this yielded a grim exception, possibly because the `other` array contains `null`s:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (192.168.0.5 executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.sql.types._create_row)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:773)
...
```

I know the UDF machinery works for simple scalars.  I tested a `toUpper()` function on a different column and the UDF worked fine.

Almost all of the other `move` data is much more "SPARK friendly".  It is the `other` field and the array-of-array substructure that is vexing.

Any guidance most appreciated.
P.S.  All my pyspark logic is pipelined functions; no SQL.  I would greatly prefer not to mix and match.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `transform` as a general loop exploiting the binary form of the lambda that also passes the current index into the array.  Here is a solution:

```
        #  Translation:                                                                                                                                                                 
        #   select 1:  Get only even moves and call the output a "temporary" column 'X'                                                                                                 
        #   select 2:  X will look like this [ [{null,null,["0:03:00"]},null,{null,null,["0:02:57"]},...]                                                                               
        #              This is because the dfg.moves.a is an array in the moves                                                                                                         
        #              array. In this example, we do not further filter on the                                                                                                          
        #              entries in the 'a' array; we know we want a[0] (the first one).                                                                                                  
        #              We just want ["0:03:00",null,"0:02:57",...]                                                                                                                      
        #              x.clk will get the clk field but the value there is *also*                                                                                                       
        #              an array so we must use subscript [0] *twice* to dig thru                                                                                                        
        #              to the string we seek                                                                                                                                            
        #   select 3:  Convert all the "h:mm:ss" strings into timestamps                                                                                                                
        #   select 4:  Walk the deltas and return diff to the next neighbor.                                                                                                            
        #              The last entry is always null.                                                                                                                                   
        dfx = dfg\
            .select( F.filter(dfg.moves.a, lambda x,i: i % 2 == 0).alias('X'))\
            .select( F.transform(F.col('X'), lambda x: x.clk[0][0]).alias('X'))\
            .select( F.transform(F.col('X'), lambda x: F.to_timestamp(x,"H:m:s").cast("long")).alias('X'))\
            .select( F.transform(F.col('X'), lambda x,i: x - F.col('X')[i+1]).alias('delta'))

        dfx.show(truncate=False)
        dfx.printSchema()

+---------------------------------------------------------------+               
|delta                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 9, 16, 0, 6, 3, 8, 5, 2, 12, 4, 4, 10, 0, null]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- delta: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

If you want to compactify it you can do so.

```
dfx = dfg\
    .select( F.transform(F.filter(dfg.moves.a, lambda x,i: i % 2 == 0), lambda x: F.to_timestamp(x.clk[0][0],"H:m:s").cast("long")).alias('X') )\
    .select( F.transform(F.col('X'), lambda x,i: x - F.col('X')[i+1]).alias('delta'))
```